# What happened to the answer?

Tags: discussion

The question is this :[Why didn't my Level 1 Barbarian become Level 2 when donated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264518/donation-problem)

Yesterday I got an answer of that question but today that answer was not there. What happened to that answer?

Comment: chances are it was deleted, either by the poster themselves, mod or by 3 regular community members. you need 10,000 rep to be able to [view deleted questions and answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: The answer was deleted by review because it was not an answer. See [this meta on NAA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/214193) and [this one on the VLQ review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/214193)

Comment: For reference, the content of the answer was: "*Huh, really. I never knew that that if you donate a troop of level 1, it will automatically become level 2. I am also in a clan called Battlewolves which is lvl 9 clan and my all troops are lvl 5 so you mean that I will donate any kind of troop of lvl 5 it would be changed to lvl6. I don't think so!*", @DeMize you might note that it doesn't answer your question of why your barbarian didn't upgrade nor whether or not what you encountered was a glitch.

Comment: Ok, thanks for telling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has been deleted. Only users with 10,000+ reputation can view deleted answers.

It does not say wether it was community, mod or user deleted, but the user who posted it has deleted their account, and it appears to have been voted for deletion by atleast 2 users for not answering the actual question.